# Running GUI from a container on a mac resolve in "libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found"

Tags: macos, docker, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run a container based on *ubuntu:15.10* from my Mac.

I run the following command

```
docker run -i -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/. -e DISPLAY=192.168.0.104:0 --privileged mycompany/mycontainer
```

(The IP was taken from my en0: inet using ifconfig)

I'm getting the following error:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  25
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

This container runs on another team member Ubuntu OS without any issues.

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

If your container is attempting to run Chrome in the script then you can use Chrome's [SwiftShader](https://swiftshader.googlesource.com/SwiftShader) software renderer - which works with XQuartz 2.7.11:

```
chromium-browser --use-gl=swiftshader
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue running SUMO simulation GUI out of a docker container in MacOS.

As a temporary solution or workaround, what worked for me was to **downgrade XQuartz Version to 2.7.8**, as also suggested in https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96433

I am still getting the error but the GUI does work.

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded Xquartz to version 2.7.8 but my app opens like black window and instantly closes. Logs of this container contain the same problem:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
...
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed:
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(matrix): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(opacity): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed: 
""
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(qt_Matrix): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed: 
""
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(matrix): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(opacity): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed: 
""
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(qt_Matrix): shader program is not linked
```

Comment: If you have a related problem please leave a comment instead of an answer, if you think you can add some more information send a new answer linking the original and adding your information.